# jvm crashed and so glassfish v2.1 died because of 'dependency_failed'

Tags: jvm, glassfish

Never happened before. The following is the jvm crash log.
full of dependency_failed error msg. did a google search, some people was saying it is a bug if you were using -XX largePage kind of thing. But I am not using that option. 
Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: did not know how to post xml, so it was not readable at all, sorry about that.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hotspot_log version='160 1' process='7791' time_ms='1291395740597'>
<vm_version>
<name>
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
</name>
<release>
17.1-b03
</release>
<info>
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.1-b03) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_22-b04), built on Sep 15 2010 01:07:59 by &quot;java_re&quot; with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)
</info>
</vm_version>
<vm_arguments>
<args>
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz -Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathPrefix= -Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathSuffix= -Dcom.sun.aas.ServerClassPath= -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars.ee= -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars=admin-cli.jar,admin-cli-ee.jar,j2ee-svc.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.excludesList=admin-cli.jar,appserv-upgrade.jar,sun-appserv-ant.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain.ee= -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain=webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath.ee=/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,/lib/dbstate.jar,/lib/hadbm.jar,/lib/hadbmgt.jar,/opt/sun/mfwk/share/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath=/usr/share/glassfish/lib/install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars.ee=appserv-se.jar,appserv-ee.jar,jesmf-plugin.jar,/lib/dbstate.jar,/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,jgroups-all.jar,/opt/sun/mfwk/share/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars=javaee.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/../lib/tools.jar,install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,com-sun-commons-launcher.jar,com-sun-commons-logging.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqxm.jar,webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar,mail.jar,appserv-jstl.jar,jmxremote_optional.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,activation.jar,appserv-rt.jar,appserv-admin.jar,appserv-cmp.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/updatecenter/lib/updatecenter.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/jbi/lib/jbi.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,dbschema.jar -Dcom.sun.aas.configName=server-config -Dcom.sun.aas.configRoot=/usr/share/glassfish/config -Dcom.sun.aas.defaultLogFile=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/logs/server.log -Dcom.sun.aas.domainName=xyz -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/usr/share/glassfish -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceName=server -Dcom.sun.aas.processLauncher=SE -Dcom.sun.aas.promptForIdentity=true -Dcom.sun.appserv.pluggable.features=com.sun.enterprise.ee.server.pluggable.EEPluggableFeatureImpl -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory -Dcom.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages=javax.help,javax.portlet -Dcom.sun.enterprise.taglibs=appserv-jstl.jar,jsf-impl.jar -Dcom.sun.enterprise.taglisteners=jsf-impl.jar -Dcom.sun.updatecenter.home=/usr/share/glassfish/updatecenter -Ddomain.name=xyz -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/glassfish/lib/endorsed -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/../lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/../jre/lib/ext:/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/lib/ext:/usr/share/glassfish/javadb/lib:/usr/share/glassfish/lib/jdbcdrivers -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/glassfish/lib:/usr/share/glassfish/lib:/usr/share/glassfish/lib -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/login.conf -Djava.security.policy=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/server.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager -Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.ee.admin.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/cacerts.jks -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver -Djmx.invoke.getters=true -Dnet.spy.log.LoggerImpl=net.spy.memcached.compat.log.Log4JLogger -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -Xms4608m -Xss2048k -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Xmx4608m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/logs/jvm.log 
</args>
<command>
com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch start
</command>
<launcher>
SUN_STANDARD
</launcher>
<properties>
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.version=17.1-b03
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing
java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/../lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/../jre/lib/ext:/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/lib/ext:/usr/share/glassfish/javadb/lib:/usr/share/glassfish/lib/jdbcdrivers
java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/glassfish/lib/endorsed
sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/amd64
java.library.path=/usr/share/glassfish/lib:/usr/share/glassfish/lib:/usr/share/glassfish/lib
java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre
java.class.path=/usr/share/glassfish/lib/jhall.jar:/usr/share/glassfish/lib/appserv-launch.jar
sun.boot.class.path=/usr/share/glassfish/lib/endorsed/activation.jar:/usr/share/glassfish/lib/endorsed/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar:/usr/share/glassfish/lib/endorsed/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/usr/share/glassfish/lib/endorsed/webservices-api.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre/classes
com.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz
com.sun.aas.ClassPathPrefix=
com.sun.aas.ClassPathSuffix=
com.sun.aas.ServerClassPath=
com.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars.ee=
com.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars=admin-cli.jar,admin-cli-ee.jar,j2ee-svc.jar
com.sun.aas.classloader.excludesList=admin-cli.jar,appserv-upgrade.jar,sun-appserv-ant.jar
com.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain.ee=
com.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain=webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar
com.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath.ee=/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,/lib/dbstate.jar,/lib/hadbm.jar,/lib/hadbmgt.jar,/opt/sun/mfwk/share/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar
com.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath=/usr/share/glassfish/lib/install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar
com.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars.ee=appserv-se.jar,appserv-ee.jar,jesmf-plugin.jar,/lib/dbstate.jar,/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,jgroups-all.jar,/opt/sun/mfwk/share/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar
com.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars=javaee.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/../lib/tools.jar,install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,com-sun-commons-launcher.jar,com-sun-commons-logging.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqxm.jar,webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar,mail.jar,appserv-jstl.jar,jmxremote_optional.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,activation.jar,appserv-rt.jar,appserv-admin.jar,appserv-cmp.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/updatecenter/lib/updatecenter.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/jbi/lib/jbi.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,/usr/share/glassfish/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,dbschema.jar
com.sun.aas.configName=server-config
com.sun.aas.configRoot=/usr/share/glassfish/config
com.sun.aas.defaultLogFile=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/logs/server.log
com.sun.aas.domainName=xyz
com.sun.aas.installRoot=/usr/share/glassfish
com.sun.aas.instanceName=server
com.sun.aas.processLauncher=SE
com.sun.aas.promptForIdentity=true
com.sun.appserv.pluggable.features=com.sun.enterprise.ee.server.pluggable.EEPluggableFeatureImpl
com.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
com.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages=javax.help,javax.portlet
com.sun.enterprise.taglibs=appserv-jstl.jar,jsf-impl.jar
com.sun.enterprise.taglisteners=jsf-impl.jar
com.sun.updatecenter.home=/usr/share/glassfish/updatecenter
domain.name=xyz
java.security.auth.login.config=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/login.conf
java.security.policy=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/server.policy
java.util.logging.manager=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager
javax.management.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.ee.admin.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/keystore.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/mnt/xyz/glassfish_domains/xyz/config/cacerts.jks
jdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
jmx.invoke.getters=true
net.spy.log.LoggerImpl=net.spy.memcached.compat.log.Log4JLogger
sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
</properties>
</vm_arguments>
<tty>
<writer thread='1093888336'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' witness='javax/management/AttributeList' stamp='0.969'/>
<writer thread='1077066064'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/Properties' witness='com/sun/enterprise/server/pluggable/TomcatPluggableFeatureImpl' stamp='1.064'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/util/Properties' x='java/util/Hashtable put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='java/security/Provider' stamp='4.938'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/util/Properties' x='java/util/Hashtable put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='java/security/Provider' stamp='4.938'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/Hashtable get (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='java/security/Provider' stamp='4.938'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/Hashtable get (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='java/security/Provider' stamp='4.938'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/Hashtable get (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='java/security/Provider' stamp='4.938'/>
<writer thread='1102293328'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='javax/management/modelmbean/DescriptorSupport' witness='com/sun/jbi/management/config/DescriptorSupport' stamp='7.167'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='javax/management/modelmbean/DescriptorSupport' witness='com/sun/jbi/management/config/DescriptorSupport' stamp='7.167'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='javax/management/modelmbean/DescriptorSupport' witness='com/sun/jbi/management/config/DescriptorSupport' stamp='7.167'/>
<writer thread='1077066064'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/Stack' witness='com/sun/corba/ee/impl/util/RepositoryIdPool' stamp='9.659'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/messaging/jmq/util/lists/SimpleNFLHashMap' stamp='18.608'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/messaging/jmq/util/lists/SimpleNFLHashMap' stamp='18.608'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/messaging/jmq/util/lists/SimpleNFLHashMap' stamp='18.608'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/messaging/jmq/util/lists/SimpleNFLHashMap' stamp='18.608'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/messaging/jmq/util/lists/SimpleNFLHashMap' stamp='18.608'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/messaging/jmq/util/lists/SimpleNFLHashMap' stamp='18.608'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<dependency_failed type='abstract_with_unique_concrete_subtype' ctxk='java/nio/ByteBuffer' x='java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' witness='java/nio/DirectByteBuffer' stamp='18.819'/>
<writer thread='1249380688'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap keySet ()Ljava/util/Set;' witness='com/sun/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap' stamp='24.181'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap containsKey (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' witness='com/sun/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap' stamp='24.181'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap containsKey (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' witness='com/sun/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap' stamp='24.181'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/HashMap containsKey (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' witness='com/sun/org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap' stamp='24.181'/>
<writer thread='1093888336'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/ThreadLocalInvoker$1' stamp='29.756'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/ThreadLocalInvoker$1' stamp='29.756'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/sun/jersey/server/impl/container/servlet/ThreadLocalInvoker$1' stamp='29.756'/>
<writer thread='1100192080'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList get (I)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='com/xyz/recommendation/ItemScoreList' stamp='33.412'/>
<writer thread='1077066064'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/security/cert/CertificateException' witness='java/security/cert/CertificateEncodingException' stamp='36.591'/>
<writer thread='1213659472'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/BufferedReader' witness='org/apache/coyote/tomcat5/CoyoteReader' stamp='51.776'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/io/Reader read ([C)I' witness='org/apache/coyote/tomcat5/CoyoteReader' stamp='51.776'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/io/Reader read ([C)I' witness='org/apache/coyote/tomcat5/CoyoteReader' stamp='51.776'/>
<tty_done stamp='9223.439'/>
</tty>
<hotspot_log_done stamp='9223.439'/>
</hotspot_log>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: As far as I can tell, The only errors are a bunch of dependency_failed for different packages in the jvm crash log.

Comment: please see the edited question. All the dependency_failed elements are errors I suppose.

Comment: can you post your jvm options (these are found in the serverconfig ~ JVM settings)

Comment: Is there anybody found the solution for this issue?